# Given graph $G$ that is "close" to another graph $G'$ can we find certain bipartite subgraph of $G$

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, probabilistic-method

Suppose that $G$ is a graph with $2n$ vertices and $n^2$ edges. Let $\epsilon>0$. We say that $G$ is $\mathbf{\epsilon-close}$ to $K_{n,n}$ if
$$\frac{|E(G)\triangle E(K_{n,n})|}{\binom{2n}{2}} \leq \epsilon.$$

I would like to show that there exists some partition $V(G)=A_1 \dot\sqcup A_2$ such that the number of edges in $G$ with one end in $A_1$ and one end in $A_2$ is at least $(1-\epsilon)n^2$; that is,
$$e(G[A_1, A_2]) \geq (1-\epsilon)n^2.$$

I believe that this can be proven by showing that the expected number of edges between partition sets $A_1$ and $A_2$, where the parts are each of cardinality $n$, is at least $(1-\epsilon)n^2$, given that $G$ is $\epsilon$-close to $K_{n,n}$. If I can prove this, then I know that the partition I want exists.

One can interpret $\frac{|E(G)\triangle E(K_{n,n})|}{\binom{2n}{2}} \leq \epsilon$ $\,$ as saying that the probability that a pair of vertices $\{x,y\}$ is either an edge in $E(G)$ or an edge in $E(K_{n,n})$, but not both, is less than or equal to $\epsilon$ (assuming $\epsilon \leq 1$). Then this means that the probability that a pair of vertices $\{x,y\}$ is an edge in both $E(G)$ and $E(K_{n,n})$ or in neither of these edge sets is at least $1-\epsilon$.

I am not sure where to go from here. It seems that the expectation that I want to compute is conditional, but I do not know how to use the fact that $G$ is $\epsilon$-close to $K_{n,n}$.

Any help is immensely appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What’s $k$?  If we’re trying to partition the full set of $2n$ vertices, this should be trivial by following the partition induced by $K_{n,n}$.  But I suspect there is more context that we want there to be a smaller(?) partition depending on the parameter $k$.

Comment: @ErickWong My apologies, I meant $n$ not $k$. I fixed this.

Comment: In that case it is quite simple, no need for probability at all.  The copy of $K_{n,n}$ which is close to $G$ already comes with an implied partition of the vertex set.  Just use that and estimate how close $G$ would be to $K_{n,n}$ if the number of edges going across is *not* as high as requested.

Comment: @ErickWong Is the implied partition the partition already given by $V(K_{n,n})$?

Comment: Yes, that’s the one.